# Add constant raster into Equation in ArcPy Script

Tags: arcpy, indentationerror

In last equation instead of multiplying 0.98 , i just want to replace it by constant raster and multiply by constant raster (ras_LUE) , below is my updated code for adding constant raster. but its not working,
Error massage

```
IndentationError: expected an indented block  


 #i tested both line to add after ras_WSCALAR but error massage displaying 
 ras_LUE = getRaster(D:\MOD-REF\NDVI\LUE-CASA.img)
 ras_LUE = arcpy.raster (D:\MOD-REF\NDVI\LUE-CASA.img)
```

In below code i want to add

```
for ras_num in [str(i).zfill(3) for i in range(1, 13)]:
        # get required rasters for current month number
        ras_APAR = getRasterFromList(ras_num, lst_ras_APAR, ws_in_apar)
        ras_TSCALAR = getRasterFromList(ras_num, lst_ras_TSCALAR, ws_in_tscalar)
        ras_WSCALAR = getRasterFromList(ras_num, lst_ras_WSCALAR, ws_in_wscalar)

        # verify if raster are valid
        if all([not ras_APAR is None, not ras_TSCALAR is None, not ras_WSCALAR is None]

            # 0.98 will replace by constant raster (ras_LUE) 
            #ras_NPP = (ras_APAR * ras_TSCALAR * ras_WSCALAR * 0.98)
            ras_NPP = (ras_APAR * ras_TSCALAR * ras_WSCALAR * ras_LUE)
```

Comment: Your error message has nothing to do with map algebra, it's pure Python

Comment: Yes. I am doing it on on python. Instead of 0.98 value in equation, i just want to give constant raster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

indentation error means that the number of spaces to start your block is incorrect. For example, your blank line after "if" is missing. The are other typo error on your example: all() not closed, missing : after if statement etc. Please check your code and remove all blank rows to identify your indentation error.

As for your new line, text needs to be written between '' or "" and Python is case sensitive

> ras_LUE = Raster("D:\MOD-REF\NDVI\LUE-CASA.img")

Comment: i ran the line but i am getting following error `NameError: global name 'Raster' is not defined`

Comment: yes. I have done it by adding the line` ras_LUE = arcpy.Raster("D:\MOD-REF\NDVI\LUE-CASA.img")`